# docker compose gives "exited with code 0" while docker run works

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-11

Let's say, I have this easy `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  foo:    
    container_name: bar
    build: .
```

for the sake of completeness, I also want to share that simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
```

My folder structure is

```
temp
|- docker-compose.yml
|- Dockerfile
```

---

When I build the container with `docker compose build`, it gives no errors:

```
[+] Building 0.1s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:87da********************************************************bb35                                         0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/temp-foo                                                                                             0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

The outpot of that is identical to `docker build . -t foo`. When I run it with `docker run -dt --name bar foo`.

When I now issue `docker compose up`, I get `bar exited with code 0`:

```
[+] Running 2/2
 - Network temp_default  Created                                                                                                     0.0s
 - Container bar         Created                                                                                                     1.9s
Attaching to bar
bar exited with code 0
```

How is this possible or even make sense. Shouldn't both fail or work?
I can share the Dockerfile if needed, it's close to that one.

Comment: It'd be very helpful if you did [edit] the question to include a [mcve].  Without knowing what's actually in the Dockerfile or the application it's very hard to say what's causing this behavior.  The one obvious difference is that you have a `docker run -t` flag but not a corresponding Compose `tty: true` option.  It seems unlikely that would make a difference for most programs but it could be worth trying.

Comment: I included a MWE Dockerfile now - you're right that it didn't contain the option/line `tty: true`. I'll give that a try. Note to myself: `docker run [-t/--tty] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]` does "Allocate a pseudo-TTY".